# PNP Modern Search - shuffling results or sorting by relevance?

Tags: search, search-results, pnp, pnp-search-webparts

I'm using the PNP Modern Search results webpart to create a "related results" sidebar to add to each of my pages in the IT knowledge base I'm creating. I have it set to show results that match the page category (like if the page is about Outlook, it only shows Outlook-related pages). However, I don't want it to show the same 5 results on every page.

Is there a way I can either:
(a) sort my results by relevance, so like, it looks at my page content (not sure if there's a managed property that has all my page content or anything), finds other pages that might be kind of similar, and displays those?
(b) just shuffles the results?

I'm still really unfamiliar with how searching works in general, so I'm not sure if this is a silly question.